# Django Rest Framework Elastic Search: RequestError 400 parsing_exception

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl

When trying to query for event documents that match this condition, I'm getting a parsing exception and I'm not sure what's causing it. This is occurring in my custom get_queryset method. In my get_query in my document view set I'm getting an error.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    user = self.request.user

    if hasattr(user, 'userprofile'):
        user_universities = user.userprofile.universities.all().values_list("id")
        user_universities_campus = user.userprofile.universities.all().values_list("main_campus__id")


        query = query | Q('bool', must=[
            Q('match', visibility_scope=Event.UNIVERSITY),
            Q('bool', must=[
                Q('terms', university__id=list(user_universities)),
                Q('bool', should=[
                    Q('terms', university__main_campus__id=list(user_universities)),
                    Q('terms', university__main_campus__id=list(user_universities_campus))
                ])
            ])
        ])

    qs = qs.query(query)
    return qs
```

I'm getting this error:

```
        if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 91, in count
        return c()
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\search.py", line 679, in count
        **self._params
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 84, in _wrapped
        return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 529, in count
        "POST", _make_path(index, doc_type, "_count"), params=params, body=body
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 358, in perform_request
        timeout=timeout,
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 261, in perform_request
        self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
      File "C:\Users\fendy\.virtualenvs\cul\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py", line 182, in _raise_error
        status_code, error_message, additional_info
    elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[terms] unknown token [END_ARRAY] after [university.id]')
```

Query String printout:

```
Bool(should=[Bool(must=[Match(visibility_scope=2), Bool(must=[Terms(university__id=[(42809,)]), Bool(should=[Terms(university__main_campus__id=[(42809,)]), Terms(university__main_campus__id=[(None,)])])])]), Match(visibility_scope=0)])
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the query after terms. Can you please update your question with the query string by printing it before return qs.

Comment: @Fenz242, the error is caused by elasticsearch query being not in the right format. Can you please update the query string not like the bracket() type.

Answer (score 0):

Your query in string should be like this:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should":[
      "bool" : {
        "must":[

          {"match":{
          "visibility_scope" : 2

          },
          "bool":{
            "must":[
              {
                "terms": {

                }
                ....
                .....
                .....

              }
              ]
          }

          }
        ]
      } 
    ]



}

}
```

Can you update your question with a querystring? I may be able to complete it.

Comment: Yes I printed the querystring or do you mean something else?

Comment: you have to write the query in string format as I mentioned in the answer. please have a look at elasticsearch keywords. All of them start with small laters and in the query there should be no `= ` instead `:` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of queryset. Please set flat=True.

```
user_universities = user.userprofile.universities.all().values_list("id", flat=True)
```